# Can we install snap packages and other apps like firefox through AppCenter?

Tags: release-loki, apps

Can the AppCenter do it just like how Ubuntu Software does?

It seems like AppCenter lacks lots of apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is already available in AppCenter.

AppCenter doesn't support the installation of Snap packages at this time

Answer (score 3):

i think if you want you can, since loki is built on ubuntu 16.04 first install snapd

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

then install snap applications normally.

For example to install a simple app just run `sudo snap install hello` to see the installed app use `snap list` to run an installed app use `snap run hello`

if you need to know more how to manage and install snap apps refer this link https://goo.gl/aFfwvM

Comment: Your link doesn't go to a relevant page? https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=howtogeek